# jqgrid TreeGrid with frozen columns is not working

Tags: jquery-plugins

currently frozen columns can not be setup with TreeGrid .Here Is the [Link](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3afrozencolumns#limitations)

I tried the solution suggested at this site: https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/pull/420
to freeze columns on treegrid. It freezes the column and expanding the nodes work fine for all levels of the tree. However, collapsing row is not working for me if the tree level is more than three. Is anyone successful in using frozen columns with TreeGrid?

I am using jqgrid version: 4.4.4

Thank you in advance for your help!

Best Regards